# PHP fgets() to array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgets

**I want to get the first line of my Foo.csv as an array.**

Foo.csv:

```
I, Like, Chocolate
And, Also, Milk
```

I tried

```
//$foo is Foo.csv
$file = fopen($foo, "r")
//First attempt
$fgetsFile = fgets($file)
//Other way
$streamlineFile = stream_get_line($file, 10000, "\n");
fclose($file)

var_dump($fgetsFile) // (String) "I", "Like", "Chocolate"
var_dump($streamlineFile) // (array) [0] => (string) "I", "Like", "Chocolate"
```

I would like to end up with an array like this:

```
array([0] => "I", [1] => "Like", [2] => "Chocolate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this more easily using fgetcsv(). Take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and corresponding example, then maybe use something like this (tested):

```
if(($file = fopen($foo, "r")) !== false){
    if(($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
        var_dump($data);
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Indeed. I just checked. Thanks.